# What does '>' do when used in the context of columns?

Tags: columns

I don't understand what `>` does in:

```
>{\centering}
```

which I've seen used for centering text in columns such as:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
```

If it's possible I'd like to know what `>` does in general, but since it can have a lot of uses, if it's very long it's okay with just explaining how it works in my example.

Oh, and if this question is too basic tell me how to search for these things and where, because I've tried searching in this website and google and some others and I can't find it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It inserts the `\centering` directive at the very beginning of every cell in the column. Thus these cells will have a fixed width, and their content will be centred both horizontally and vertically. See the documentation of the `array` package.

Comment: Welcome! Did you try checking the manual for the `array` package?

Comment: I think there should be an `\arraybackslash` after that `\centering`. Take a look at the documentation of `array` and the explanation of the `\arraybackslash` macro.

Comment: @Skillmon not necessarily. It is only needed in the final column and only if the table uses `\\ ` rather than `\tabularnewline` to end the table rows.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle true, but imho one should mention that... (and who uses `\tabularnewline`?)

Comment: "who uses `\tabularnewline?`"  people who have `\centering` in their tables (that's why I added it to latex:-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    >{stuff}
```

Just inserts `stuff` at the start of the cell so if the column is `>{stuff}p{3cm}`  then it works as if the column was `p{3cm}` but every cell in that column started with `stuff`.

it is often used with declarations such as `\centering` but can be used with any tokens that can be used in a cell.